# push notification from UrbanAirship not working with live server (i.e. with production key ) in android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

In one of my android app, I am using **push Notification from Urban Airship.**

The problem with the app is that when I am using the development key for the push notification its working perfect (The app get registered & APID generated) but when I am using the production key , It does not work at all(The APID not generated).

However, I have configured the app for production key properly (Like in airshipconfig.properties, 
**1) set key for production key 
2) making inProduction = true.**

Still its  not working .

I am getting the error :

**App name- UAlib  Stop connnecting . In a holding pattern.**

on logcat, everytime I am trying to connect it with the live server (production key).

Any idea or help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've not experienced this problem, however I've found that the UA developers are quick to respond on their own forums - you'd probably be more successful asking there... Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your free trail period(as you are using the helium transport)  for the push notification from Urban airship have been finished.
So you have two options:
1) Either you take some paid plan from urban airship
2) Or go for c2dm transport.

The c2dm transport does not need to have any plan.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my UA experience this most likely is a sever side problem. Verify that all of the required fields are correctly filled out for the production key. If the problem persists create a test 'Application' on the UA site with the correct application credentials to verify it is NOT a credentials problem. Other than that contact UA and have them better troubleshoot the issue.

The required fields on the site for the application to function correctly on Android is the 'Android Package' and 'C2DM Authorization Token', plus make sure to tick 'Push Notifications Support'.